# converting jupyter notebook to PDF in FireFox in Ubuntu 20.04 using pyppeteer

Tags: python, pdf, latex, jupyter, nbconvert

I am shown this option to convert my jupyter to PDF (how should I fix it?)
[image]

But when I try it, I get the following error:
[image]

This is rather weird error since I am using Firefox not Chromium browser.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-chromium), https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-chromium :

> For converting notebooks to PDF with --to webpdf, nbconvert requires the Pyppeteer Chromium automation library.

> Pyppeteer makes use of a specific version of Chromium. If it does not find a suitable installation of the web browser, it can automatically download it if the --allow-chromium-download flag is passed to the command line.

So, even if you use Firefox for browsing, you need Chromium to convert notebooks to PDF with this exporter based on [Pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) (`--to webpdf`).

You coud also try using `--to pdf`, which makes the conversion to PDF via LaTeX, but you should have LaTeX installed in your system.

Or you could try [notebook-as-pdf](https://pypi.org/project/notebook-as-pdf/) (`--to PDFviaHTML`), but I think it is also based on `Pyppeteer`.